# i am confused what file extension should i use

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Like for example, i have a page that has a form  that asks the user to enter their name and last name and that form will be directed to a php file but at the same time, that page(form) has a mysql code because it shows the current names of the users that were recently added so will my file be saved as .php or .html?

Comment: if it has PHP code it'll save with .php otherwise PHP code will not work with default Apache config

Comment: You sure about that? got evidence?

Comment: @MuppetGrinder - I thought by default Apache didn't treat .html files as containing anything other than HTML; has that been changed?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would separate your server side scripting from your client side pages, calling them though either includes on an intermediary rendering php page, or ajax on a static html page.

a quick rule of thumb: If it has logic, interacts with backend resources or performs a calculative function, then it's php, if it provides structure to the output then it's html and if it provides blueprint for the presentation of the layout it's css.

Answer (score -1):

Of course php!

if you are using php your pages must be in php otherwise your code will not get rendered.

you fill up the gaps using:

e.g: `<span><?php echo $yourVariable; ?></span>`

$yourVariable is either extracted from Database or has been defined